# Error happened while executing Lua script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have splash version 3.0 installed on my server and when I am trying to render specific URL from splash UI i.e. "http://localhost:8050/"  from browser, it is giving me below:

```
{
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "error": 400,
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 2,
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:2: http403",
        "error": "http403",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR"
    } }
```

It is not getting render for specific URL only, while working fine for most of the cases

```
script = """
    function main(splash, args)
      splash.resource_timeout = 20.0
      splash:go(args.url)
      splash:wait(10.0)
      splash.scroll_position={0, 600}
      return splash:html()
    end
"""

HTML_SCIPT1 = """
        function main(splash, args)
            splash:go(args.url)
            splash:wait(20.0)
            splash:set_viewport_full()
            return splash:html()
        end
        """


splash_args = {
    'wait': 10.0,
    'iframes': 1,
    'html': 1,
}
```

def start_requests(self):
urls = url_list

```
    for i in urls:
        try:
            url = i.name
            if 'http' not in url:
                url = 'http://' + url

            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                meta={'site': i},
                                dont_filter=True,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={'lua_source': script, 'timeout': 70})
            
            """
            dev version
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                  callback=self.parse,
                  meta={'site': i},
                  dont_filter=True,
                  endpoint='execute',
                  args={'lua_source': HTML_SCIPT1, 'timeout': 60},
                )
            """
        except BaseException as e:
            log.write_exeption(e)
            log.write_info('Something wrong in custom Request')
            log.write_error('start request: request failed on: ' + str(i))
            continue

def parse(self, response):
    site = response.meta['site']        
    ex = URLExtractor(response)
    urls = ex.extract_link()
    
    if not urls:
        AdsSpider.spider_status.save_page(site, response)

    if not urls:
        log.write_info('WTF!!! site: {} no urls, status: {}'.format(site, response.status))
    for i in urls:
        try:
            yield SplashRequest(url=i,
                                callback=self.parse_ads,
                                meta={'site': site},
                                dont_filter=True,
                                endpoint='render.json',
                                args=splash_args,
                                )
            
            """
            dev version
            yield SplashRequest(url=i,
                  callback=self.parse_ads,
                  meta={'site': site},
                  dont_filter=True,
                  endpoint='execute',
                  args={'lua_source': HTML_SCIPT1, 'timeout': 60},
                )
            """
        except:
            log.write_error('Invalid request')
            log.write_error('parse: site - {0}, url - {1}'.format(site, i))
            return
```

Comment: It is scraping, scrape, scraper - scrap is something completely different.

Comment: I am new in this area and exploring it so don't exactly aware about terminologies but I am trying to render page using splash UI from browser. I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you upload the code you've used?

Comment: Added some code snippets

Comment: Just for information that when I am running docker using --net=host argument it is running fine for the sites which is creating issue while running docker without this argument.  --  docker run --net="host" -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash:3.0